# how to view a winmail.dat file attached to a case in Salesforce?

Tags: attachment, configuration

When users recieve emails to the case, the attachements are atatched to the case under notes and attachements. Certain emails contain winmail.dat files. Whow can these be viewed easily through the browser? For example, in the attachmwnt sectio of the case, selecting the view url beside the winmail.dat downloads the winmail.dat file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no option to view it directly in the browser like you have with e.g. word or excel files. Closest you can get is to install a winmail.dat viewer like [Winmail Opener](http://download.cnet.com/Winmail-Opener/3000-2369_4-10469892.html?tag=sideBar;downloadLinks), and make that the default opener for .dat files (can be set in the app). Then in your browser click 'view' and it will ask you if you want to open in Winmail Opener. Except for Google Chrome, which will always download the file first.

Alternatively, ask the sender of the file to change their attachment format. You can find further information on winmail.dat here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Neutral_Encapsulation_Format

Answer (score -2):

Winmail.dat file contains attachment in encoded format and can be open through any [Winmail Opener](http://www.freeviewer.org/winmaildat/).

Thanks